# Show product attributes on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

Do you know any trick for showing product attributes on product page not only on comparative page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the attributes you want to be displayed in the product page from `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` and set the flag `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to `yes`. A reindex might be required.

Comment: Hi Marius. thanks alot. can you clue me how to add this attribute into order process? Let's say that i have a bike and some customer prefers a specific frame size, but that bike came in different frame sizes. How can i add a drop-down where he can select frame size and complete the order. The frame size will not affect the price...

Comment: @IonuţCălugăru. Welcome to SE.Let's keep this website clean. If the answer helped you solve the problem, mark it as accepted. If you have other questions use the [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link. Don't mix them.